# Where is the Vendor module in YII Initializr?

Tags: php, yii, initializr

I have installed YII Initializr module and YII framework is in my PHP Include path. 
But as soon as I run `mysite/frontend/www/index.php`,
I get this error:

```
Warning: require(./../../common/lib/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\yiiinit\frontend\www\index.php on line 12    
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './../../common/lib/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\yiiinit\frontend\www\index.php on line 12
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here are the steps to generate vendor autoload.php file.

Step 1. Create account on https://github.com and go into setting => Personal access tokens i.e. https://github.com/settings/tokens

Step 2. Generate github access token.

Step 3. Now open command prompt (cmd) and go into the folder where yii installed and run command => composer update (Note:- there should be a composer.json file).

Step 4. cmd require Token form your side now copy token generated in step 2 and paste it in cmd.

Step 5. Yii2 Frameworke installed successfully now browse web/index.php

Comment: I'm missing something in step 4.  I'm not clear what the command is supposed to look like.

Comment: @JustinGrant - Command is in step 3. That is for updating composer like,

$ composer update

After "$ composer update" command console will ask for TOKEN then paste it on console(cmd)

Answer (score 0):

Missing `/vendor/autoload.php` file is generated automatically by composer after package installation.

You must first install composer (sell [documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/)). Then run 
    php composer.phar install
or if installed globally
    composer install
in the directory where `composer.json` file is located

Answer (score 0):

With experience it seems that composer does not download the vendor folder with a slow internet connection. If composer returns any error when installing the basic application try downloading it manually and then work from there possibly composer failed to generate the folder.

Here is a link to the basic yii2 app: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/releases/download/2.0.11/yii-basic-app-2.0.11.tgz

Answer (score 0):

1  Create/Sign in into github account.

2 Go to Profile>>Settings>>Personal access tokens (OR) click on this https://github.com/settings/tokens.

3 Click on Generate new token

4 Select the appropriate scopes and click Generate token.

5 Copy the the token Key and past it in composer when the composer want you the Token(like: Token (Hidden):)

Now it will enter into the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using composer, 
install **mbstring** for your PHP version and run `composer install` again